# Edit a specific item's value for a key of a plist

Tags: objective-c, plist

I have a plist. I want to edit values for key called "FAV" when a button clicked. But I can't make it change. How can I do it? Thank you.

```
[[self.dataList objectAtIndex:ind] setValue:@"0" forKey:@"FAV"];
```

Here is a part of plist:

```
<plist version="1.0">
    <array>
 <dict>
<key>ID</key><string>1</string>
<key>SEARCHNAME</key><string>key1</string>
<key>ISGROUP</key><string>0</string>
<key>CODE</key><string>000.0</string>
<key>NAME</key><string>Name1</string>
<key>PARENTID</key><string>0</string>
<key>FAV</key><string>0</string>
</dict>
 <dict>
<key>ID</key><string>2</string>
<key>SEARCHNAME</key><string>key2</string>
<key>ISGROUP</key><string>0</string>
<key>CODE</key><string>000.0</string>
<key>NAME</key><string>Name2</string>
<key>PARENTID</key><string>0</string>
<key>FAV</key><string>0</string>
</dict>
```

Comment: Hum, can you give more informations ? It's pretty hard to tell. Does it crash ? etc.

Comment: No. if the value of FAV for that item is 0, it doesn't change into 1.

Comment: Well, it shouldn't, regards to your code

Comment: What is dataList ? A NSArray you load from the plist ?

Comment: dataList is NSMutableArray. I defined it in .h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is datelist?? i think its dic.

Read the dictionary from file ,then update the dictionary then write that dictionary back into the file.

Comment: Is there no short way? It sounds not effective. Because there will be just one item to edit from 10000 items.

Comment: Instead of reading keep one editing copy and write it into file when u update it.

Comment: I made it like you said. Thanks.